# How do I add a separate background animation?

Tags: css, animation, background

I'm doing this project for school, and I need to know how to use this separate background animation I made.

I tried doing a separate DIV block but no luck so far.
Can anyone help me?

This is my current code:

```css
.bg {
  animation: bg;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes bg {
  0% {
    background-color: hsl(180, 100%, 90%)
  }
  17% {
    background-color: hsl(240, 100%, 90%)
  }
  34% {
    background-color: hsl(300, 100%, 90%)
  }
  51% {
    background-color: hsl(0, 100%, 90%)
  }
  68% {
    background-color: hsl(60, 100%, 90%)
  }
  85% {
    background-color: hsl(120, 100%, 90%)
  }
  100% {
    background-color: hsl(180, 100%, 90%)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bg" />
<div class="question">
  <h1>Baseball Quiz</h1>
  <h3>Made by Lordust</h3>
  <p>
    <a href="xhtml/question1.xhtml">Click here to start</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```css
.bg {
    animation: bg;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes bg {
  0% {background-color:hsl(180, 100%, 90%)}
  17% {background-color:hsl(240, 100%, 90%)}
  34% {background-color:hsl(300, 100%, 90%)}
  51% {background-color:hsl(0, 100%, 90%)}
  68% {background-color:hsl(60, 100%, 90%)}
  85% {background-color:hsl(120, 100%, 90%)}
  100% {background-color:hsl(180, 100%, 90%)}
}
```

```html
    <head>
        <title>Baseball quiz</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bg"/>
        <div class="question">
            <h1>Baseball Quiz</h1>
            <h3>Made by Lordust</h3>
            <p>
                <a href="xhtml/question1.xhtml">Click here to start</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
```

```
animation-duration: 4s;
```

in bg class.